# How to set limits on periodical values in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have a set of three equations in my script that are fairly simple, yet they use sin and cos values, thus making me to set a limit on them. Below are those equations:

```
y1 = 23/200 - cos(q1)*((67*cos(q2 + q3))/100 - (17*sin(q2))/25 + 13/50)

y2 = - sin(q1)*((67*cos(q2 + q3))/100 - (17*sin(q2))/25 + 13/50) - 47/50

y3 = 67/100 - (17*cos(q2))/25 - (67*sin(q2 + q3))/100
```

I obviously tried 'limit' to set individual limit before using 'solve' function, as follows:

```
y1 = Pax - eq1;
y2 = Pay - eq2;
y3 = Paz - eq3;

limit(y1,q1,-1);
limit(y1,q1,1);
limit(y1,q2,-1);
limit(y1,q2,1);
limit(y1,q3,-1);
limit(y1,q3,1);

limit(y2,q1,-1);
limit(y2,q1,1);
limit(y2,q2,-1);
limit(y2,q2,1);
limit(y2,q3,-1);
limit(y2,q3,1);

limit(y3,q1,-1);
limit(y3,q1,1);
limit(y3,q2,-1);
limit(y3,q2,1);
limit(y3,q3,-1);
limit(y3,q3,1);

rozw=solve(y1,y2,y3,'q1,q2,q3');
q1_1 = rozw.q1
q2_1 = rozw.q2
q3_1 = rozw.q3
```

I also tried this with the 'left' and 'right' limit, yet, I still end up with not only wrong values, but values exceeding my limits.

Could you possibly suggest some solutions?

Comment: Where did you find that 'limit' is used to give values to the limits of solve?

Comment: Can't tell you right now, I think that somebody suggested it on Matlab forum - or maybe I misinterpreted his/her clues a bit.

Comment: Isn't `limit` only calculataing the actual limits of a certain given function as you would do when studying a function?

Comment: as far as I know you are just asking to calculate the limit of `yn` functions for `qn` tending to `+1/-1`.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to do - to limit yn fuction for qn tending to +m/-n. Thinking of it, I feel like you might be right about 'limit' giving the actual limits of a function.

Comment: @KrystianMeresiński: `limit` does not limit your function in the meaning of upper/lower bounding your function; `limit` retrieves the value that a function or sequence "approaches" as the input or index approaches some value. but maybe I'm misunderstanding your point.

Comment: Damn. Guess I'll need to dig deeper, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I infer that you're using the Symbolic Toolbox, then you can use [`assume()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/symbolic/assume.html):

```
syms q1 q2 q3
assume([q1 >= -1 & q1 <= 1
        q2 >= -1 & q2 <= 1
        q3 >= -1 & q3 <= 1])
```

Comment: I don't use Symbolic Toolbox, do you know a way to set boundaries some other way?

Comment: Your statement is in contradiction with the code you posted. 
What do you get with `whos q1`?

Comment: q1, q2 and a3 are the joint angles of my robot manipulator, if thath's what you're asking. I do use symbolics, but outside of Symbolic Toolbox - whole code is in plain Matlab editor. Do you suggest I should give this toolbox a try? I've never used it before, editor suited my needs just fine.

Comment: Are you aware that a Toolbox is mostly just a bunch of functions and dedicated classes? In other words, if you have symbolic variables in the workspace then you ARE using the symbolic toolbox. You can ignore my first line in the code, and check the documentation for assume() which is already linked.

Comment: After using it in the Editor i get following error: "
Error in ==> sym.sym>sym.ge at 823
            notimplemented('ge')"

After double-checking in Symbolic Toolbox I get "Error: Illegal character '&' [line 1, col 18]".

You surely have noticed by now that I'm fairly new to Matlab and its enviroment. I simply don't feel comfortable yet - could you fill me with some books/tutorials, if you have one beside you?

Comment: You can start with the [Getting started guide](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html) and then with [Getting started with Symbolic Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/symbolic/getting-started-with-symbolic-math-toolbox.html). If you create an account with TMW you will have access to .pdf documentation from the root page of each section.